# Questions about crawler using python and scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am assigned to create a crawler by using python and scrapy to get the reviews of a specific hotel. I read quite a number of tutorials and guides, but still my code just keeps generating an empty CSV file.

Item.py

```
import scrapy


class AgodaItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    StarRating = scrapy.Field()
    Title = scrapy.Field()
    Comments = scrapy.Field()
```

Agoda_reviews.py

```
import scrapy


class AgodaReviewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'agoda_reviews'
    allowed_domains = ['agoda.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.agoda.com/holiday-inn-express-kuala-lumpur-city-centre/hotel/kuala-lumpur-my.html?checkIn=2020-04-14&los=1&adults=2&rooms=1&searchrequestid=41af11cc-eaa6-42cc-874d-383761d3523c&travellerType=1&tspTypes=9']

    def parse(self, response):
        StarRating=response.xpath('//span[@class="Review-comment-leftScore"]/span/text()').extract()
        Title=response.xpath('//span[@class="Review-comment-bodyTitle"]/span/text()').extract()
        Comments=response.xpath('//span[@class="Review-comment-bodyText"]/span/text()').extract()
        count = 0

        for item in zip(StarRating, Title, Comments):
            # create a dictionary to store the scraped info
            scraped_data = {
                'StarRating': item[0],
                'Title': item[1],
                'Comments': item[2],
            }

            # yield or give the scraped info to scrapy
            yield scraped_data
```

Can anybody please kindly let me know where the problems are? I am totally clueless...

Answer (score 0):

Your results are empty because scrapy is receiving a response that does not have a lot of content. You can see this by starting a scrapy shell from your terminal and sending a request to the page you are trying to crawl.

```
scrapy shell 'https://www.agoda.com/holiday-
inn-express-kuala-lumpur-city-centre/hotel/kuala-lumpur-my.html?checkIn=2020-04-14&los=1&adults=2&rooms=1&searchrequestid=41af11cc
-eaa6-42cc-874d-383761d3523c&travellerType=1&tspTypes=9'
```

Then you can view the response that scrapy received by running:
`view(response)`
That should open the response that was received and stored by scrapy in your browser. As you should see, there are no reviews to extract from.

Also, as you are trying to extract some information from span-elements, you can run `response.css('span').extract()` and you will see that there are some span-elements in the response but none of them has a class that has anything to do with Reviews.

So to sum up, agoda is sending you a quite empty response. As a consequence scrapy is extracting empty lists. Possible reasons could be: Agoda has figured out that you are trying to crawl their website, for example based on your user agent, and is therefore hiding the content from you - or they are using javascript to generate the content.

To solve your problem you should either use the agoda api, make yourself familiar with user agent spoofing or check out the selenium package which might help with javascript-heavy websites.